# Can't see harddrive folder in ftp client

Tags: vsftp

I've mounted my hard drive to my Raspberry Pi using a [tutorial](http://www.techjawab.com/2013/06/how-to-setup-mount-auto-mount-usb-hard.html) I mounted the drive in /media/movies. The problem is that when I connect my Raspberry Pi to an FTP client, I can only see the "home" and "python games" folder; I see no directory named /media/movies.

Yesterday, when I unmounted my hard drive and plugged it into my main PC to see if the files where there, is saw all the files but no folder named /media/movies but i can transfer files to the location /media/movies.

My question is how can I fix the hard drive so that I can see the directory with the hard drive in the FTP client?

Comment: Please give more information as to what commands you used to mount and how did you ftp into RPi. Random referencing to links is not considered good here. By the way, you could mount your hard-drive in your home folder itself.

Comment: i used all the commands in the link to mount it into my RPi, if i mount it to my home folder will all the files in it follow along? and to mount the harddrive the path is /dev/sda1 /home/pi/media/movies ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, it seems to me maybe `/home/pi` is not the FTP data placement directory.

Are you entering Rasp Pi FTP server with user `pi`?

You could also check drive is mounted well checking with

```
df -h
```

Have in consideration that FTP data folder is the user home folder, so you also would have to check that `/home/pi` is `pi` user home folder with

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep Pi | awk -F':' '{print $6}'
```